# I am trying to display the largest and smallest number of the three values I input

Tags: c++, algorithm, function

It is an assignment I am working on. I'm pretty sure it is something minor that I have missed, but seeing that I am trying to work on this late in the night after studying for other classes, I believe another set of eyes can help me. I am supposed to have something like this:

```
please enter first value---> 5.2
please enter second value---> 1.0
please enter third value-->7.1

smallest value: 1.0
largest value: 7.1
```

However is get some weird numbers like 002C128F for smallest value and 002C128A for largest value.
I would appreciate any feedback given. I am not asking to have my homework done. I just want some guidance seeing that I am stuck. Perhaps my `if` statements are wrong? Thank you for your time.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double min2 (double &a, double &b,double &c)
{  
    double min=0;

    if(a<b)
        min= a;
    else 
        min=b;

    if (c<b)
        min=c;

    return min;
}    

double max2(double &a, double &b, double &c)
{   
    double max=0;

    if(a>b)
        max=a;          
    else 
        max=b;

    if (c>b)
        max=c;

    return max;        
}

int main()
{ 
    double a,b,c=0;

    min2(a,b,c);
    max2(a, b, c);

    cout << "Author: Jose Soto.\n";

    cout<<"enter first value: ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"enter second value: ";
    cin>>b;
    cout<<"enter third value:";
    cin>>c;

    cout<<"The smallest value is: "<<min2<<endl;
    cout<<"The largest value is: "<<max2<<endl;

}
```

Comment: Others have found your specific bug, but *please* fix your indentation, you'll find it much easier in the future to find problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return values from your `min2` and `max2` functions are never used. You're printing the addresses of the functions.

Maybe you're looking for:

```
// ...
cout << "The smallest value is: " << min2(a, b, c) << endl;
cout << "The largest value is: " << max2(a, b, c) << endl;
```

You have to call the functions after you've got the user input, not before that.

Answer (score 1):

`cout<<"The smallest value is: "<<min2<<endl;` prints the address of the function, it doesn't call it.

Change it to

```
cout<<"The smallest value is: "<<min2(a,b,c)<<endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what has already been told, you also have a logical error in your functions:

```
if (c<b)
  min=c;
```

Should be

```
if (c<min)
  min=c;
```

Similarly for max.

Answer (score 1):

You get some weird numbers because you pass to functions min2 and max2 uninitialized variables a and b. You only initialized variable c with 0.

```
int main()
{ double a,b,c=0;

   min2(a,b,c);
   max2(a, b, c);
```

At first you have to enter values for variables a, b, c and only after that to call min2 and max2.

Also the functions theirselves are invalid. And there is no any need to declare their parameters as references.

And in these statements

```
cout<<"The smallest value is: "<<min2<<endl;
cout<<"The largest value is: "<<max2<<endl;
```

you do not call the functions. You output their addresses.

The valid code could look the following way:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double min( double a, double b, double c )
{  
   double min = a;

   if ( b < min ) min = b;
   if ( c < min ) min = c;

   return min;
}

double max( double a, double b, double c )
{   
    double max = a;

    if ( max < b ) max = b;
    if ( max < c ) max = c;

    return max;
}

int main()
{ 
    double a, b, c;

    cout << "Author: Jose Soto.\n";

    cout << "enter first value: ";
        cin >> a;
    cout << "enter second value: ";
        cin >> b;
    cout << "enter third value:";
        cin >> c;

   cout << "The smallest value is: " << min( a, b, c ) << endl;
   cout << "The largest  value is: " << max( a, b, c ) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that standard C++ library has already functions std::min and std::max. For example you could call them as

```
std::min( { a, b, c } );
std::max( { a, b, c } );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int findMax(int a, int b, int c)
{
 if(a > b)
 {
   if(a > c)
   {
    return a; 
   }
   else
   {
     return c;
   }
 }
 if( b > c)
 {
   return b; 
 }
 else
 {
   return c;
 }
}

main()
{
  int a,b,c;

  cout<<"enter first value: ";
  cin>>a;

  cout<<"enter second value: ";
  cin>>b;

  cout<<"enter third value:";
  cin>>c;

  cout<<"\nA : "<<a<<endl;
  cout<<"\nB : "<<b<<endl;
  cout<<"\nC : "<<c<<endl;
  cout<<"\nMax : "<<findMax(a,b,c)<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Wow. 20 lines of code for a function that can be implemented more readably in *one* line of code.

Answer (score -1):

The following two functions:

```
double min2 (double &a, double &b,double &c)
double max2(double &a, double &b, double &c)
```

You have used `&` followed by the variable name.The `&` is used to call the function using-call by address(i.e it uses a pointer which stores the address of the parameter sent during function call.
There are 2 types of function calls:
1.Call by Value
2.Call by Address
Call by value only copies the value and is usually used if the changes made aren't to be reflected onto the original variable.
eg:

```
void increment(int a)
{
a++;
cout<<a;
}
int main()
{
int x=5;
cout<<x;
increment(x);
cout<<x;
return 0;
}
```

Output:
5
6
5

So use the functions without `&`s

Comment: You're passing _references_, not pointers. For the same reason, attempting to use the dereference operator will not even compile...